# Making a particle accelerator with nanomaterials

Tags: particle-physics, neutrons, nanoscience

In typical particle accelerators, protons are sped up by the electric field. From what I've read, neutrons can also be accelerated, by first accelerating protons and somehow converting them into neutrons before they hit the target. How is this done exactly?

I've wondered how else one could go about creating a neutron accelerator, whether it would be possible to do so using nano-materials(nm). If there was some nm with a lattice that prevented neutrons from entering, and was also narrow enough to prevent a neutron from reflecting backwards, could you create a linear accelerator that acted as a 'gun' to shoot a target? If you have a chamber of neutrons and heat them up to the appropriate energy, then releasing the pressure via hundreds of nanotubes that converge to a single target, could this achieve a collision?

[image]

Comment: Just how are you going to keep neutrons from entering?

Comment: neutrons are neutral unstable particles, ( they decay after some minutes free of nuclear forces  that contain them in nucleons). There is no way to keep them penned anyplace (except in neutron stars, but that is another story). Sorry but this question makes no physics sense.

Comment: So it isn't possible to make a pressurized container that holds any subatomic particle?